# Creating a form from Django's Official Tutorial

Tags: python, django

I have completed the Django Official Tutorial, and I have been trying to create a form based off of our existing model. So in addition to being able to create polls/choices from the admin screen, I want to replicate this as a form that a user can interact with.

However, when I actually submit the form on the html-rendered page, I get an integrity error returned.

```
IntegrityError at /polls/add_poll/
polls_question.pub_date may not be NULL
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/add_poll/
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
polls_question.pub_date may not be NULL
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 485
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.8
```

With a traceback to:

```
C:\Users\Paul.Zovighian\desktop\project\mysite\polls\views.py in add_poll
            form.save(commit=True)
```

I am not sure how I am supposed to alleviate this, I have included an 'initial = datetime.now() to the ModelForm but that hasn't fixed things.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Question, Choice
from datetime import datetime

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question_text = forms.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the question.")
    pub_date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial = datetime.now())

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text',)
```

models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

views.py

```
def add_poll(request):
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database.
            form.save(commit=True)

            # Now call the index() view.
            # The user will be shown the homepage.
            return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {})
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = QuestionForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render(request, 'polls/add_poll.html', {'form': form})
```

Hopefully this information is enough to help someone help me! Happy to provide anything else. Any tips on my approach are also more than welcome, I am very new to django!

Cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is, you have the form with the fields `pub_date` set to hidden type, but in the meta, you exclude it. Now, when you exclude it, the hidden type is not being set in the form, and when the object is set to be created, it fails, as it does not find a required attribute.

To fix this issue, change:

```
fields = ('question_text',)
```

to

```
fields = "__all__"
```

Here is the relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

---

Now, An alternate fix would be (though not covered in the documentation yet), instead of the form, you can set the default at the model level. For that, you would do:

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

So, every time an insert is performed into the database, django checks and assigns the specified default value if nothing has been specified against that field.

You can read more on [default values here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#default)

Comment: I recommend not using fields="__all__" and not setting a default to datetime.now since it does not include a timezone aware datetime. See my answer below.

Comment: Huh. I do not disagree with you,  But this is the official tutorial.  For someone starting out, your answer is way too much IMO. Hence i would not recommend taking that route

Comment: I think the way you put forward is bad practice and OP would be best copying the correct practices lead until he understands the concepts. Else he'll just run into problems later.

Comment: I do think django tutorial knows what it is doing.  More than you and me. Ill just leave it there. :)  cheers

Answer (score 0):

Best is to remove

`pub_date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial = datetime.now())`

from the `QuestionForm` and modify `fields`

`fields = ('question_text', 'pub_date', )`

If `pub_date` can bu `null`

`pub_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)`

To make the `pub_date` hidden in your form override `__init__`

`def __init__(self):
  self.fields['pub_date'].widget = forms.widgets.HiddenInput()`

and set the Model field `default=timezone.now`